# How can I make this Asian font highlighting macro recognize between-word characters?

Tags: vba, ms-word, asianfonts

For most of the documents I work with, I need to highlight instances of Asian font (such as SimSun, MS Mincho).

I put together the the code below - it works well but it doesn't highlight Asian font characters within non-Asian words (such as the apostrophe in "it's").

```
Sub HighlightAsian2019()
Dim aWord
    For Each aWord In ActiveDocument.Words
        If aWord.Font.Name = "SimSun" Then
           aWord.FormattedText.HighlightColorIndex = wdTurquoise
        End If
    Next aWord
    For Each aWord In ActiveDocument.Words
        If aWord.Font.Name = "MS Mincho" Then
           aWord.FormattedText.HighlightColorIndex = wdTurquoise
        End If
    Next aWord
End Sub
```

Can anyone help me improve the code so that ALL instances of SimSun and MS Mincho in the text are highlighted?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why not simply run a find loop instead of iterating through words. it will find any thing with that particular font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use this Loop:**

```
Sub HighlightAsian2019()

With ActiveDocument.Range

    For i = 1 To .Characters.Count
        If .Characters(i).Font.Name = "SimSun" Then
            .Characters(i).FormattedText.HighlightColorIndex = wdTurquoise
        End If
    Next

End With

End Sub
```

You can use the `.Characters` property of Range to access the alphabets. Add another If condition for other fonts to check

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have that particular font, I tested with other fonts, may try with modifying the font names.

```
Sub test()
Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = ThisDocument.Content
With Rng.Find
.ClearFormatting
.Text = ""
.Font.Name = "Kruti Dev 040 Wide"
    Do While .Execute
    Rng.FormattedText.HighlightColorIndex = wdTurquoise
    Loop
End With
End Sub
```